# macOS, change behaviour of "Home" and "End" keys

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to change the behaviour of the "Home" and "End" keys on an external keyboard? I mean, I don't want to move to the end or beginning of a page while writing by pressing those keys, instead, I want to move to the end or beginning of the LINE where I'm focused, just like in Linux or Windows. I don't want to use the combination of "command + arrow left/right"

Comment: [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) [freeware] *(We really ought to have a canonical for 'change shortcuts', with either Karabiner, BetterTouchTool, USB OverDrive or "You really don't want to do that!" as potential answers, depending on specifics of question.)*

Comment: Thank you very much